# No "Signing" Tab on Visual Basic .Net Standard Projects in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-standard

When creating a .Net Standard (Visual Basic) project in Visual Studio, the properties window presents no "Signing" tab. This is not an issue with .Net Standard (C#) projects, nor Visual Basic projects which are not .Net Standard.

Why this specific configuration, and is there any way to circumvent it?

Comment: Strong-naming assemblies is now discouraged by Microsoft.  Is it something you need to do for a specific reason or do you just think that you should?  If it's the latter, don't.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be referenced by multiple projects which are also strong-named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I never found a way of automatically signing an assembly through Visual Studio's interface for this specific project template. However, I did find a workaround using custom build steps.

Visual Studio's interface also didn't allow this either, for whatever reason, so I had to manually edit the `.vbproj` file. Here's what it looked like in the end:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"Path\To\ildasm" /all /out=Project.il Project.dll</PostBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>del Project.dll</PostBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>"Path\To\ilasm" /dll /key="Path\To\Key.snk" Project.il</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see, all we're doing is disassembling the dll into an intermediate language file, and then reassembling it with a strong name

For the sake of simplicity (... and laziness), using project environment variables is left as an exercise to the reader :^).